# Object Attribute as List

Tags: python, python-3.x

Nevermind, it seems that no matter what authorLast is, it doesn't recognize it; it gives the same error. Could there be something wrong with the operator.attrgetter?

Thanks in advance.

Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example:

```
import operator

class Source: 
    sources_count = 0 
    list_of_sources = [] 

    def __init__(self, title, author, year, publisher, city_of_publication, summary, type, tags): #basic attributes of Source class with addition to list_of_sources
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.aSplit = author.split()
        self.authorFirst = self.aSplit[0]
        self.authorLast = self.aSplit[1]
        self.year = year
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.city_of_publication = city_of_publication
        self.summary = summary
        self.type = type
        self.tags = tags
        Source.sources_count += 1
        Source.list_of_sources.append(self)


s2 = Source("Hi", "Jacob Jenkins", "2013", "Publisher", "City", "Summary", "Print", "this, is, tag")
s1 = Source("Hoop", "Chelsea Chibbles", "2013", "Publisher", "City", "Summary", "Print", "this, is, tag")

print(s2.authorFirst)
print(s2.authorLast)
print(s1.authorFirst)
print(s1.authorLast)

key_last_name = operator.attrgetter("authorLast")
sorted_list = sorted(Source.list_of_sources, key=key_last_name)
print(sorted_list[0].authorLast, sorted_list[1].authorLast)
```

Doesn't have the error. I am now checking the rest of the code. As soon as I take those 3 parts out (the Class, the method and the function) it works fine. Maybe it does have something to do with the pickling.

EDIT: The problem seems to have fixed itself. My suspicion is that I had pickled the files previous to making the edits to the attributes, so the objects actually did not have said attributes, because they were pickled before the attributes existed. It works fine now.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example. Also, you seem to be mixing `aSplit` and `a_split`.

Comment: what do you mean by reproducible example?

Comment: Ideally, a code sample that we can run. Or at least a sample that would allow us to understand what's going on. Right now we don't know whose `__init__` you show (although probably `Source`'s) and what `list_of_sources` is (probably a list of all instances) and how you create the instances. The fact that the attribute refers to a list shouldn't be a problem anyway

Comment: Correct on both counts. I think something with the attrgetter might be wrong.

Comment: `attrgetter` attempts to access the attribute you want it to. But you can use `key_last_name = lambda x: x.authorLast` to doublecheck. The actual problem is somewhere else in the code you don't show us. We can't assume that you've done everything right there, or there wouldn't be a problem

Comment: <gazing in crystal ball> You are creating a list of Source instances, and the `__init__` method shown is the initializer for Source. Your code to create the Sources includes a name that does not include a space, so splitting the name only gives a 1-element list. Accessing the [1]th element of this list raised an exception, so you wrapped the code in a try-except to keep going. Now you have a Source instance *that has no authorLast attribute*. Other than that, I've got nothin'.

Comment: +1 @Paul, a silently caught exception is what I had in mind, too.

Comment: that doesn't explain it. All "authors" have spaces.

Comment: Maybe so, but there is at least one Source with no `authorLastName` - the loop that checks using `hasattr` should have found it.

Comment: I guarantee you, there is none! I have been doing experimenting from scratch, adding Source class instances manually, making sure they all have authorLastName, and they do when I check, but for some reason when I run it through the Sorted function it disappears! Look at my most recent edit.

Comment: Try `key_last(s1)` or `key_last(s2)`. Betcha they raise the same error?

Comment: Try this then, in place of operator.attrgetter:  `key=lambda x:getattr(x,"authorLastName","")` This will *always* give a value, regardless of your success or failure in getting the 'authorLastName' attribute. I am wondering why you assign the results from `pickle.load(input2)` to `Source.list_of_sources`, as this list should be built up for you as you create (or unpickle) Source instances. Try doing this: `for src in Source.list_of_sources: print (src.__dict__)` and see just what the heck your instances have in them.

Comment: Also: Could you try distilling it into a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (e.g. without depending on external files, and removing as much code as possible while keeping the same error) so we can debug this without crystal ball?

Comment: Your latest edit uses "authorLast", not "authorLastName"

Comment: Your raw experimenting is with a different Source class than the one you posted - the Sources you create interactively have `authorLastName` attributes, but the code you posted calls it `authorLast`.  Has the class code changed since you pickled the objects? Or are you accidentally importing the Source class from two different .py files?

Comment: Sorry, no. There is one file that the class is being imported from, and that has authorLastName.

Comment: Then why are you posting code with attribute "authorLast"? I think you wrote some code, pickled some instances, then changed the attribute name, and now unpickling the instances gives you strange objects.

Comment: Nope. The code was slightly different simply because I re-wrote it all in a test file to find the problem (SSCCE) and I slightly changed the attribute name. It wasn't that that was the problem. The problem was:

"My suspicion is that I had pickled the files that contained the sources previous to making the edits to the attributes, so the objects actually did not have said attributes, because they were pickled before the attributes existed. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After building your list, skim through `Source.list_of_sources` like this:

```
for src in Source.list_of_sources:
    if not hasattr(src, "authorLast"):
        print (src.aSplit)
```

See if you get any Source instances that don't have an `authorLast` attribute.

**EDIT**:

Here is a safer way to assign first/last name, in case you get an author with just 1 name:

```
self.asplit = self.author.split()
if len(self.asplit) == 1:
    self.asplit.append('')
self.authorFirstName = self.asplit[0]
self.authorLastName = self.asplit[-1]
```

This also helps if the author is something like "F Scott Fitzgerald", giving you a first name of "F" and a last name of "Fitzgerald". Explicitly picking asplit[1] for the last name would erroneously give "Scott".

Comment: thanks, but the problem still remains, even if it is not 1 name

Comment: This is probably the answer that aided me the most. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You must have a bug elsewhere in your script.  The *attrgetter* works just fine for both strings and lists:

```
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> class Book:
    def __init__(self, author):
        self.author_split = author.split()
        self.author_first = self.author_split[0]
        self.author_last = self.author_split[1]
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Book(%r)' % ' '.join(self.author_split)


>>> books = Book('Stephen King'), Book('Dean Koontz')
>>> sorted(books, key=attrgetter('author_first'))
[Book('Dean Koontz'), Book('Stephen King')]
>>> sorted(books, key=attrgetter('author_last'))
[Book('Stephen King'), Book('Dean Koontz')]
>>> sorted(books, key=attrgetter('author_split'))
[Book('Dean Koontz'), Book('Stephen King')]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Source' object has no attribute 'aSplit'

Comment: @Aristides, what did you run? There is no `aSplit` reference anywhere in RH's code.

Comment: oh sorry i ran

self.asplit = self.author.split()
if len(self.asplit) == 1:
    self.asplit.append('')
self.authorFirstName = self.asplit[0]
self.authorLastName = self.asplit[-1]